# Can you run After Effects on Azure Batch?

Tags: after-effects, azure-batch

I am wondering if it is possible to install Adobe After Effects as an 'application' in Azure batch. If so does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried it yet. I did do some research around this though and it looks possible.

It appears we need:

- A VM image (like [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-rendering-applications) prebuilt images)
- Containing [aerender.exe](https://helpx.adobe.com/africa/after-effects/using/automated-rendering-network-rendering.html)
- With a blank file called `ae_render_only_node.txt`

  - in `C:Users/Public/Public Documents/Adobe` (to enable [non-royalty bearing mode](https://helpx.adobe.com/africa/after-effects/using/automated-rendering-network-rendering.html#non_royalty_bearing_mode))

It looks like a user did it [here](https://community.adobe.com/t5/after-effects/virtualizing-ae-installs-for-cloud-based-rendering/td-p/8772018?page=1), though not specifically in Azure Batch.